# Find the previoius Element with a certain class

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a jQuery dialog which allows users to add and remove options to a vote (using jQuery to update the DOM). Every time an option is added, an input and a button ('Delete') are added to the dialog in the following format -

```
<div id="existing-options">
    <div class="dialog-option">
        <div class="dialog-right">
            <div class="remove_option button-secondary" id="remove_new_0">Delete</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dialog-left">
            <input type="text" value="1" class="option text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="new_0" name="new_0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the users presses enter when they are focused on an input, the `click` event for it's corrisponding 'Delete' button is fired.

I've done some research and `.sibling()` seems inappropriate. `.prev()` seemed like my best option, but that isn't working. Could someone please tell me the best way to get this working?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    dialog_options_container = $('#existing-options'); // The container which holds the option inputs/buttons

    /** Capture the 'enter' key when removing an option */
    dialog_options_container.bind('keyup', '.option', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
        $(this).prev('.remove_option').click();
        return false; // Ignore the default event
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: In your javascript what means `t.dialog_options_container` ?

Comment: You could simply make the enter key have a function just as the delete button has instead on binding a function. So say you click event is to .remove() the parent just do if (e.which=== 13) { $(this).parent().remove(); } just a small example since I am on my phone haha.

Comment: @Epsil0Ner - I've updated the question to show that.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete: where in you HTML is `existing-options`?

Comment: @Sébastien - Check again please.

Comment: We are still missing the relevant code. With the sample you provided there is no way to know what `t` is. Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: try [`.prevAll('.remove_option')`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Comment: @Sébastien - The `t` is irrelevant, and I've removed it from the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t.dialog_options_container = $('#existing-options');
t.dialog_options_container.on('keyup', '.option', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) $(this).closest('.dialog-option').find('.remove_option').click();
    return false;
});
```

It uses [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select `.dialog-option` then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for `.remove_option`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The selector `.option` is added dynamically using jQuery, so doesn't exist on ready.

Comment: @DavidGard - I've just updated it so it should be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try targetting the button by `id` specifically (presume the 0 in your example increments with each new section):

```
t.dialog_options_container.bind('keyup', '.option', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#remove_' + button_id).trigger('click');
        return false; // Ignore the default event
    }
});
```

**--edit--** try this to get the correct element...

```
$('.dialog-left input[type="text"]').bind('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#remove_' + button_id).trigger('click');
        return false; // Ignore the default event
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working. I've output the value of `button_id` when I click and it's telling me that it is `existing-options`, which is actually the ID of the parent container referenced by `t.dialog_options_container`. I wasn't expecting that element to be `this`, and now it means I don't know which input had focus when the enter key was pressed...

Comment: Thanks, but your edit could never work. The `.dialog-left` DOM element (could be numerous with that class) is added dynamically via jQuery, so doesn't exist when the bind is created.